# How does one limit path animation to selected frames?

Tags: animation

I have an object that needs to follow a path from frame 440 to 500. Regardless of what I do, the animation starts at frame 1. It is my understanding that "In Range" limits this action UNTIL the start frame is reached, and it concludes at the END frame. Is that wrong?

[image]

Comment: You can animate your object with the Offset value of the constraint. But if you've pressed on the constraint Animate Path button, it will automatically move the object, in that case if you need to set the animation manually you need to remove the curve's Generator modifier in the Graph Editor and keyframe the Evaluation Time of the curve in the Object Data > Path Animation panel, is it what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I created the "follow path" animation by selecting the cylinder, then the curve, then clicked CRL-P -> Follow Path. So I don't have modifiers as a result of this action.

Comment: it automatically creates a constraint, not a modifier, check your constraint panel

Comment: I'm running 3.1, I should have mentioned that. No constraints were created. I'm adding them manually to follow your suggestions.

Comment: Oh ok my bad, actually Ctrl P > Follow Path automatically creates a modifier for the curve, you can remove it in the Graph Editor, in the left panel select the Evaluation Time track, then open the N panel > Modifiers > remove the modifier

Comment: Once you've removed this modifier you can instead give a Follow Path constraint to the object and play with the Offset value

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Follow Path* automatically creates a modifier for the curve, you can remove it in the *Graph Editor*, in the left panel select the *Evaluation Time* track, then open the *N* panel > *Modifiers* > remove the modifier. Once you've removed this modifier you can instead give a *Follow Path* constraint to the object, with the curve as *Target*, and play with the *Offset* value.